# How to do multiple math equations in one MySQL database update?

Tags: php, mysql, equation

I have a MySQL database row that stores the attempts and average score of a game:

```
+-----+----------+-----------+
| uid | attempts | avg_score |
|  4  |    3     |    15     |
+-----+----------+-----------+
```

After a user finishes the game, I want to update the two tables to figure out the new average based upon the new trial.
I want to:
multiply (attempts * avg_score = 45)
add trial_score to total avg_score (avg_score(45) + trial_score(5) = 50)
divide (avg_score(45) + trial_score(5) / attempts = attempts + 1)

This is a bit over my head with PHP mySQL statements. I will show my attempt below.

```
$sql=("UPDATE gamescore SET attempts = attempts + 1,avg_score = ((attempts * avg_score + ?) / (attempts = attempts + 1)) WHERE uid=?");
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ii",$_POST['trial_score'],$_SESSION['uid']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Failed.. obviously... What do I need to correct here?
Thanks!

Comment: If the individual numbers that are used in the calculations are stored in the database then do NOT store the results of calculations in the database.  Calculate when selecting or after selecting.

Comment: i dont understand why? its perfectly valid to do `attempts = attempts + 1`, which is stored in the database and used in the equation, right?

Comment: That's just incrementing a value which is fine.  I see now that you are not storing `trial_score` so your approach may be OK.

Comment: And what is _Failed_?  Query error or bad numbers updated in the row?

Comment: yes, i store that in a statement above which logs every attempt. but how do i correct this to make it work? I keep getting synax error. my guess is the math equation, it already works for the column = column + 1

Comment: update `gamescore` set attempts = (attempts+1),avg_score = ((attempts * avg_score + 5)/(attempts+1)) where id ='1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  must divide with `(attempts + 1)` and not `(attempts = attempts + 1)`.
Also set the value of `avg_score` first and then `attempts` because if you set `attempts` first then the value in the expression that sets the value of `avg_score` MySql will use the modified `attempts` (you can find more [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)):

```
UPDATE gamescore  
SET avg_score = (attempts * avg_score + ?) / (attempts + 1),
    attempts = attempts + 1 
WHERE uid = ?;
```

Comment: awesome, thank you! i should have known about the attempts. I thought about it but wasnt sure. tested and working perfectly